# MySQLi select distinct order by another column

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL DB:

```
variable    displayname    clevs      ccols    cmin    cmax  show_on_quicklinks  client
'capesfc'   'cape'         '100 200'  '18 19'  '100'   '3400' 'gfs,access-c'     NULL
'lftxsfc'   'li'           '-10 -9'   '50 52'  '-10'   '0'    'gfs'              NULL
'lftxsfc'   'li'           '-10 -9'   '50 52'  '-10'   '0'    'gfs,access-c'     'client1'
'tscreen'   'tempsfc'      '-10 45'   '50 52'  '-10'   '45'   'gfs,access-c'     'client1'
'lftxsfc'   'li'           '-10 -9'   '50 52'  '-10'   '0'    'access-c'         'client2'
'capesfc1'  'cape1'        '100 200'  '18 19'  '100'   '3400' 'gfs,access-c'     NULL
```

I want to select unique displayname where client is not empty, otherwise just return displayname... so in the example below if I select client='client1', it'll return the rows for client1 and also must return all other rows where client is NULL.  It must not return any other rows for other clients:

```
variable   displayname  clevs      ccols    cmin    cmax  show_on_quicklinks    client
'lftxsfc'  'li'         '-10 -9'   '50 52'  '-10'   '0'    'gfs,access-c'       'client1'
'tscreen'  'tempsfc'    '-10 45'   '50 52'  '-10'   '45'   'gfs,access-c'       'client1'
'capesfc'  'cape'       '100 200'  '18 19'  '100'   '3400' 'gfs,access-c'        NULL
'capesfc1' 'cape1'      '100 200'  '18 19'  '100'   '3400' 'gfs,access-c'        NULL
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show us some code

Comment: Something similar to this where I can specify client, it returns the row for client1 if it exists, otherwise will return the row where client = ''

    SELECT t1.* FROM (SELECT * FROM `variables_info` WHERE `client` = 'client1') t1 WHERE (SELECT * FROM `variables_info` WHERE `client` = '') t2 t2.`variable` <> t1.`variable`

Comment: I got something that actually returns data but it's returning it all in a single row instead of 2 rows.  I need it to return t1.* and t2.* as rows? 

SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM (SELECT * FROM `variables_info` WHERE `client` = '') t1, (SELECT * FROM `variables_info` WHERE `client` = 'client1') as t2 WHERE t1.variable <> t2.variable

Comment: I believe my revised answer meets the most recent change to your expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a variation on your query at rextester.com/UIJK63292

```
SELECT
     a_index
    ,client 
    ,variable
    ,displayname
    ,color_info
    ,clevs
    ,ccols
    ,cmin
    ,cmax
    ,cint
    ,show_on_models_quicklinks
FROM `variables_info` 
WHERE `client` = 'client1' 
OR (`client` IS NULL 
    and `displayname` IN (SELECT `displayname` FROM `variables_info` 
                          WHERE `client` IS NULL 
                          and NOT `displayname` IN (SELECT `displayname` 
                                                    FROM `variables_info` 
                                                    WHERE `client` = 'client1')
                         )
   )
;
```

nb: I am GUESSING that you just want any displayname not already covered by client1 which is returned by this:

```
SELECT `displayname` FROM `variables_info` 
WHERE `client` IS NULL 
and NOT `displayname` IN (SELECT `displayname` 
                          FROM `variables_info` 
                          WHERE `client` = 'client1')
```

see http://rextester.com/LLOKZ9426

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for.  I'm not the best at trying to explain but thank you for helping out and getting the result.

Comment: Please - in future questions - include the **expected result** as a table. Trying to explain in words is so very hard. Also note how much more was achieved by providing the DDL and sample data. At stackoveflow (SO) it is referred to as an "MCVE" [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following using aggregation, but if you use upgraded version of mysql then you can use row_number() function which is better to identify duplicate easily

```
select variable,displayname,clevs,ccols,cmin,cmax,max(show_on_quicklinks) as show_on_quicklinks,max(client) as client
    from tablename
    gruop by variable,displayname,clevs,ccols,cmin,cmax
```

Comment: Oops my apologies, I forgot to add in, that I want to specify something like:

SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `client` = 'client1'.  It'll return the row for li where the client column = client1 and then for the other column where there is no client, it'll return that as well.

Comment: when you specify it in WHERE client = 'client1' then it will not return capesfc

Comment: Yeah that's right, how about something like this? it's not correct but this is what I'm after:

SELECT t1.* FROM (SELECT * FROM `variables_info` WHERE `client` = 'client1') t1 WHERE (SELECT * FROM `variables_info` WHERE `client` = '') t2 t2.`variable` <> t1.`variable`

Answer (score 0):

Revised query following change of sample:

```
set @client := 'client1';
set @var := (select variable from variables_info where client = @client limit 1);

SELECT
      variable,displayname,clevs,ccols,cmin,cmax,show_on_quicklinks,client
FROM (
    SELECT
          @row_num :=IF(@prev_value = concat(v.variable, coalesce(v.client,'')), @row_num + 1, 1)AS RowNumber
        , v.*
        , @prev_value := concat(v.variable, coalesce(v.client,''))
    FROM variables_info AS v
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_num :=1,  @prev_value :='') vars
    ORDER BY 
        v.variable, v.client
    ) AS d
WHERE (
       (RowNumber = 1 and client = @client)
    OR (RowNumber = 1 and client IS NULL and variable <> @var)
     )
```

also see: http://rextester.com/VHNDH48312

nb: The query above emulates "row_number()" which as a very useful "window function" found in MySQL 8 and many other SQL complaint databases these days.

---

oroginal:

This isn't an efficient query, but it locates the wanted 2 rows from your sample of 3.

```
select
*
from variables_info
where (variable in (select variable from variables_info where client = 'client1') and client is not null
     OR
       variable NOT in (select variable from variables_info where client = 'client1') and client is null
      )
```

see: : http://rextester.com/TAYM62841

If you have a very recent version of MySQL then better methods are available.

Comment: Thank you very much, I just tried this and it's almost working perfect.  If I have a single client it returns the correct information, however if I add another client for example called client2, it also returns the row for client2 (displayname = li).

I'm running the latest Debian 9.4 with MySQL 5.8.

Comment: if you keep changing the rules we have to keep changing the query. Take the time to generate sufficient **sample data** for us to work with AND provide the **expected result** from that data.  You have (almost) done this in the original question - just expand it. *Please note that there are 2 unnamed columns in your original sample of data.*

Comment: MySQL 5.8 doesn't offer the features needed, e.g. as Gordon Linoff mentions `row_number()` but `common table expressions` might also be relevant. MySQL v8  (now in general release) has these features

Comment: Yeah sorry about that Used_By_Already, this is my first post on here.   I'll fix up the columns in the original post, it's meant to be data that's separated by spaces for ccols and clevs columns.

Comment: no problem, but keep in mind that we need to "parse" the data to build tables. if the delimiter is a space then columns can be really hard to determine. (e.g. 1 text column can have many spaces in it). see http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-sql.htm

Comment: **top** if some columns are not required for the solution logic, just omit them.

Comment: Ok no worries, I've added quotes around the fields now and edited the data in the original post to include more data.

Comment: I've uploaded real data from the table to here and also a query I have almost got working.  You can see when I specify client='client1', it returns a row for client1 and also null for the displayname li and cape. I only want it to return the row for client='client1' for displayname, otherwise return the default row where client is NULL.  So you can see there is no entry for cape1 for client1, so it returns the default one for client = NULL. I have tried a GROUP BY displayname however it groups it using the client = NULL option.

Here is the url for the code - http://rextester.com/UIJK63292

Comment: @MikeManning `otherwise return the default row where client is NULL` only you know what that means (to you). The **BEST** way to communicate the detail of that is to show the **EXPECTED RESULT**, There is no reason why you cannot **ADD** all these details to your question (nb. in case rextester isn't available)